# Why API call is getting failed after deployment of Node JS application on Apache server?

Tags: node.js, database, oracle, apache

I have created a dashboard using React JS for [Front-end] and backend with Node JS. I have first run the `npm run build` to build the folder and then put it inside the Backend folder so whenever I give `npm start` to start my server[server.js] it will automatically able to start the project using build folder.
In local system is working fine, but when I deployed it on the Apache server, the pages are getting displayed like login, register, etc. But whenever I try to log in, register or anything it is not working.

Issue: The API call is not getting called, it is getting failed.
I am new to this whole deployment stuff so any help is welcomed.

When the user cliks on the register it will run the below code `users.js`:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//var express = require('express');
var config = require(__dirname + '../../config.js');
//var app = express();

function post(req, res, next) {
    var user = {
        email: req.body.email
    };
    var unhashedPassword = req.body.password;

    /*bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }*/

        bcrypt.hash(unhashedPassword,10,function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            user.hashedPassword = hash;

            insertUser(user, function(err, user) {
                var payload;

                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }

                payload = {
                    sub: user.email,
                    role: user.role
                };

                res.status(200).json({
                    user: user,
                    token: jwt.sign(payload, config.jwtSecretKey, {expiresIn: "60m"}),
                });
            });
        });
}

module.exports.post = post;

function insertUser(user, cb) {
    oracledb.getConnection(
        config.database,
        function(err, connection){
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }

            connection.execute(
                'insert into jsao_users ( ' +
                '   email, ' +
                '   password, ' +
                '   role ' +
                ') ' +
                'values (' +
                '    :email, ' +
                '    :password, ' +
                '    \'BASE\' ' +
                ') ' +
                'returning ' +
                '   id, ' +
                '   email, ' +
                '   role ' +
                'into ' +
                '   :rid, ' +
                '   :remail, ' +
                '   :rrole',
                {
                    email: user.email.toLowerCase(),
                    password: user.hashedPassword,
                    rid: {
                        type: oracledb.NUMBER,
                        dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                    },
                    remail: {
                        type: oracledb.STRING,
                        dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                    },
                    rrole: {
                        type: oracledb.STRING,
                        dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT
                    }

                },
                {
                    autoCommit: true
                },
                function(err, results){
                    if (err) {
                        connection.release(function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err.message);
                            }
                        });

                        return cb(err);
                    }

                    cb(null, {
                        id: results.outBinds.rid[0],
                        email: results.outBinds.remail[0],
                        role: results.outBinds.rrole[0]
                    });
                    connection.release(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
    );
}
```

And the `config.js` is the file which is conatining code for connecting to the oracle database:

```
module.exports = {
   database:{
    user          : 'something',
    password      : 'something',
    connectString : 'something'
   },
   jwtSecretKey: "something"
};
```

I think the problem here is that when the user clicks the register, it doesn't able to run the `users.js` file code or if it does able to run the `users.js` file then it doesn't able to run the `config.js` file which is having the configuration for the connection to the database.

Note: However I did able to connect to the database and do some changes to the table manually by using `sqlplus`.

Comment: I think I have found the solution, the problem is it is not running itself, the API calls are getting failed because Apache is hindering it to make the calls and need to change the `httpd.conf` file setting because I tried calling the APIs using Postman and it is successfully able to fetch the data even though the project was running on Apache server only.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `docker` for deployment. You only need two dockers configuration. One for you frontend and one for you backend and then configure the nginx to redirect the request to you frontend or to you backend if the request start with '/api'.

The `docker` configuration for you frontend is ease, just use the nginx docker an will look like this

```
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine

COPY ./dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

like you can see i'm just coping the building version of the frontend to the nginx folder so, is ready to use.

And for the backend is like the same but using a node docker file like this:

```
FROM node:10.10.0

WORKDIR /pp

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And that it.